# Find density function of sum of exponentially distributed $X_1,X_2$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, random-variables, exponential-distribution

> Let's assume that $X_1,X_2$ are independent and both obey the same exponential distribution
> \begin{align*}
> &\rho(x)=\begin{cases}
> \lambda e^{-\lambda x},& \text{ if } x\geq 0\\ 0, & \text{ if } x<0,
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
> where $\lambda >0$. Find the density function and the distribution function of $Y:=X_1+X_2$.

**My approach:**

Let be $0\leq z$ then
\begin{align*}
&P(X_1+X_2\leq z)=P(x_1\geq 0,0\leq x_2\leq z-x_1)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\rho_{x_1}(x_1)\rho_{x_2}(x_2)~\!dx_2~dx_1\\
&\underset{\text{substitution}}{=}\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\rho_{x_1}(x_1)\rho_{x_2}(x_2-x_1)~\!dx_1dx_2.
\end{align*}
If we take the definition of the exponential density function into account, we get
\begin{align*}
&\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\rho_{x_1}(x_1)\rho_{x_2}(x_2-x_1)~\!dx_1~dx_2=\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{x_2}\rho_{x_1}(x_1)\rho_{x_2}(x_2-x_1)~\!dx_1~dx_2\\
&=\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{x_2}\lambda^2e^{-\lambda x_1}e^{-\lambda(x_2-x_1)}~\!dx_1~dx_2=\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{x_2}\lambda^2e^{-\lambda x_2}~\!dx_1~dx_2
\end{align*}
At this point I don't know how to continue as in both integration bounds appear the integration variables!?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $X_1$ has density functions $\rho_{X_1}$ and $X_2$ has density $\rho_{X_2}$, then $Y = X_1 + X_2$ has density equal to the convolution of $\rho_{X_1}$ and $\rho_{X_2}$. That is
$$\rho_y(y) = (\rho_{X_1} \ast \rho_{X_2})(y) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho_{X_1}(y - x)\rho_{X_2}(x) \: dx $$

You have correctly written

$$P(Y \leq z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}\rho_{X_1}(x_1)\rho_{X_2}(x_2) \: dx_2dx_1$$

You can in fact recover the result about the convolution by differentiating your expression for $P(Y \leq z)$ with respect to $z$, using the [Leibniz integral rule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) We can then carry out the convolution integral to obtain
$$ \rho_y(y) = (\rho_{X_1} \ast \rho_{X_2})(y) = \lambda^2 y e^{-\lambda y}, \; \; y \geq 0$$

I will leave the details of the integral to you. Note that the resulting distribution is a  gamma distribution with parameters $(\alpha = 2, \beta = \lambda)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z\geq 0$. Consider a fixed value $X_1=x_1\leq z$.  Then

\begin{align*}
&P(x_1+X_2\leq z)=P(X_2\leq z-x_1)=\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\rho(x_2) dx_2
\end{align*}

(If $x_1>z$ then the integral above is zero.)

Now integrate over all values of $x_1\leq z$:

\begin{align*}
&P(X_1+X_2\leq z)=P(X_2\leq z-X_1)=\int\limits_0^z\rho(x_1)\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\rho(x_2) dx_2dx_1
\end{align*}

Now substitute the formula for $\rho$ and do the integration:
\begin{align*}
&P(X_1+X_2\leq z)=\int\limits_{0}^{z}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_1}\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2}dx_2dx_1.
\end{align*}

We have

$$\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2}dx_2=\left[-e^{-\lambda x_2}\right]_0^{z-x_1}=1-e^{-\lambda (z-x_1)}$$

and so

\begin{align*}
P(X_1+X_2\leq z)&=\int\limits_{0}^{z}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_1}\left(1-e^{-\lambda (z-x_1)}\right)dx_1\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{z}\left(\lambda e^{-\lambda x_1}-\lambda e^{-\lambda z}\right)dx_1\\
&=\left[- e^{-\lambda x_1}-\lambda e^{-\lambda z}x_1\right]_0^z\\
&=1- e^{-\lambda z}(1+\lambda z)
\end{align*}

---

If we were to do the substitution you have done, i.e. $y=x_1+x_2$ (or $x_2=y-x_1$), then we would get

$$
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\rho(x_2) dx_2dx_1&=\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\rho(y-x_1) dydx_1
\end{align*}
$$

which is different from your expression. Apart from the difference in the bounds of integration, you seem to have changed the order of integration.

How did you do your substitution? After your substitution, the outer integral (with respect to $x_2$) has a lower bound of $x_1$, so there is an error in the step where you did your substitution.

Comment: How would you go on with your approach where you did a substitution? $$
\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\rho(y-x_1) dydx_1=\dots??
$$ The integration variable $x_1$ mustn't get greater than $y$, how do you ensure this? I am wondering why you did not take $y$ as the upper bound in the first integral?

Comment: If by the "first integral" you mean the outer integral, then this is with respect to $x_1$. The substitution was for $x_2$, so has no effect on the outer integral.  If by the "first integral" you mean the inner integral, then that is with respect to $y$, so it doesn't make sense to have $y$ in the bound. (The inner integral is from $x_1$ to $z$, which means $y-x_1$ goes from $0$ to $z-x_1$. The upper bound on the outer integral ensures that $z-x_1$ is non-negative.)

Comment: I mean the outter integral. Taking $y$ as the bound of the outter integral instead of $z$ has nothing to do with the substitution but the fact that the integrand vanishes if $x_1>y$. So if you want to replace $\rho(y-x_1)$ by $\lambda e^{-\lambda(y-x_1)}$ then you have to take this into account, don't you?

Comment: But $y$ is the variable of integration on the inner integral so "disappears" after evaluating the inner integral: $\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\rho(y-x_1) dydx_1=\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\left[F(z-x_1)-F(0)\right]dx_1$, where $F$ is the distribution function associated with $\rho$. The bounds on the outer integral ensure that $x_1$ and $z-x_1$ are nonnegative.

Comment: Hmm, what if we simply decide to first integrate with respect to $x_1$? I mean I could have simply set up the double integral the other way around \begin{align*}
&P(0\leq X_2\leq z-X_1)=\int\limits_0^{z-x_1}\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\rho(x_2) dx_1dx_2=\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{z}\rho(x_1)\rho(x_2-x_1) dx_1dx_2=\int\limits_{x_1}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{x_2}\rho(x_1)\rho(x_2-x_1) dx_1dx_2
\end{align*} In this case I have to consider that $x_1\leq x_2$.

Comment: How did you come up with your integral? Why are the bounds of integration unchanged despite the order of integration changing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I simply wrote down how we calculate the probaility of $P(0\leq X_2\leq z-X_1)$.

Comment: The first equality in your last comment is not correct. The integral will (ignoring the misuse of notation from having $x_1$ represent both a dummy variable for the inner integral and a different variable as part of upper bound of the outer integral) give you an expression involving $x_1$, but  $P(0\leq X_2\leq z-X_1)$ is not a function of $x_1$ (it is a function of $z$). Try drawing the area of integration (in $(x_1,x_2)$ space).

Comment: I guess I am lacking knowledge about how to translate a set that is defined by two random variables, i.e. $X+Y\leq z$, into a double integral. Intuitively, I would say something like this: the way I started we can choose $x$ independent from $y$, so when defining the double integral the outer integral **must** refer to $x$ because we evaluate multiple integrals from inside to outside. Is this correct?

Comment: See my edit showing how the bounds of integration were obtained. Hopefully it answers your question. The upper bound of the inner integral (with respect to $x_2$) must include the variable integrated in the outer integral ($x_1$). This is the opposite off what you have described in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with that  you can use generating momentum function for the exponential distribution:
$$e^{tX_1}=e^{tX_2}=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$$

As $X_1$ and $X_2$ are indipendent we have $$e^{tY}=e^{tX_1}\cdot e^{tX_2}=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right)^2$$
This is the generating moment function of a gamma distribution $\text{Gamma}(2, \lambda)$.